# _THIS_IP_ macro in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

The following macro appears in include/linux/kernel.h

```
#define _THIS_IP_  ({ __label__ __here; __here: (unsigned long)&&__here; })
```

I don't understand what the second & applied to __here would do. The first takes the address of the local label, but what about the second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second `&` in `&&` is necessary to make GCC lookup the name as a label, instead of as a variable. For example

```
foo: ;
int foo;

void *p1 = &&foo;
void *p2 = &foo;
```

The second initializer refers to the int variable.

Answer (score 4):

I think `&&` is to get the address of label.

this is gcc extention and I don't think C99 standard supports this behavior.

[for more see this.. gcc Labels and values](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels%20as%20Values)

And [local label declaration](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Labels.html)

In your case ,

`#define _THIS_IP_  ({ __label__ __here; __here: (unsigned long)&&__here; })`

In actual code `_THIS_IP_` will be replaced by the code below of block scope

```
{ __label__ __here;
 __here: 
(unsigned long) &&__here; 
}
```

You are declaring local label `__here` . Hence to get the address of label we use `&&` while we get the address of variable with single `&`.